# Click button in react native that navigates to a difference activity

Tags: android, react-native

I have an existing android application and in the react native UI I have a button that I'd like when clicked to navigate to an activity that is not managed by react native. Is this possible?

I have created a native module already to do some other things. How could I gain access to the Application Context from within a class that extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at react-native-intent which sends the intent to a brower, and may be build you own intent https://github.com/ivanph/react-native-webintent

Also the context variable in the ReactContextBaseJavaModule is the application context. If you access to the activity context you can have a look at

[How to access Activity from a React Native Android module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704336/how-to-access-activity-from-a-react-native-android-module/32753102?noredirect=1#comment53486047_32753102)