# How to use an activity from Android in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I cannot seem to figure out the flow of using an Activity from Android in my React Native app.

I have an Android module which can do some live streaming, however, all of the streaming is handled in an Activity and all the documentation I can find on how to link React Native and Native modules only show how to use Android Views and not Activities.

Can anyone explain the process to me or a send a link?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704336/how-to-access-activity-from-a-react-native-android-module) about the issue but can't quite follow and it seems to be outdated now.

Any help would be much appriciated.